# Filtering array confusion

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic, push, splice

I have two arrays. The first array contains a bunch of values, while the second one is empty. I have a search function that checks and sees if the value is in the first array, if it is it stays in the array. However, if the value isn't in the array it needs to get taken out and put into the second array, until they clear the search and then all go back into the original array.

Lets say array1 = [0, 1];
Lets say array2 = [];

The problem I am having is after is searching, it will remove properly if I filter out the 1, but not properly if I filter out the 0.

For example:

```
          `for (i=0; i<(array1.length); i++){
             if (0 !== array1[i]){
                array2.push(array1[i]);
                array1.splice(i, 1);
            }
          }`
```

If I type 1 in my search array1 =[1] and array2 = [0]  like it should work
However, if I type 0 into my search array1 = [0,1] and array2=[] and it doesn't work.

Any idea why this is not working like how I thought it would?

Comment: Don't change the collection you're iterating over, unless you know exactly what you're doing. And `i < array1.length - 1` will skip the last element of the array.

Comment: what is `this.rows` in this context?

Comment: My bad I edited my code improperly and will fix it in the question @Gavin

Comment: Even without the - 1 it still has that problem @Andreas

Comment: Your still modifying `array1` (it's length)

Comment: If I want to iterate through all the items in array 1 then what is the proper for loop @Andreas

Comment: use `forEach` or `map`. They leave the original array as is.

Comment: @AndreNuechter That's not a problem of the `for` loop. Calling `.splice()` in `.forEach()` or `.map()` has the same effect.

Comment: @chaseter15 Just don't modify `array1`

Comment: @Andreas I tried this,

Comment: @Andreas you're right. I was of the opinion the loop would create a copy. My bad!

Comment: this.rows.forEach(element => {
                if (0 !== array1.element){
                    array2.push(array1.element)
                    array1.splice(element, 1);
                }
            });

Comment: You could also create a copy of the array using `slice()`.

Comment: And now it filters out the 0 if I put 0 or 1 into my search so it still doesn't work properly :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to remove something from one array and put it in another, you could do that with two filters to simplify your code.

```js
let array1 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
let array2 = [ ];

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', event => {
  const searchvalue = event.target.previousElementSibling.value;
  
  // The actual work:
  array2 = array1.filter(i => i == searchvalue);
  array1 = array1.filter(i => i != searchvalue);
  
  console.log(array1, array2);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1" value="5"/>
<button>Search</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const search = val => {
    for (i=0; i<(array1.length); i++) {
        if (val === array1[i]) {
            array2.push(array1[i]);
            array1.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I think, if you change the search condition, Should work fine.

Tested following scenarios
Case 1: `let array1 = [0,1]; let array2 = []; search(0)`
Case 2: `array1 = [0,1]; array2 = []; search(1)`

Comment: I will take your word for it that this works, but it doesn't in my scenario so It has to be a code issue inside of my code elsewhere perhaps. :(

Comment: Nevermind, I changed it back to what I had in the question, and now it works, even though I swear I had that before. Thank you so much! Even though my brain wants to die lol